# Code speed difference when using a random array index

Tags: c++, arrays, indexing, size-t

Given a real number X within [0,1], after a specific binning I have to identify in what bin X falls. Given the bin size dx, I am using `i = std::size_t(X/dx)` , which works very well. I then look for the respective value of a given array v and set a second variable Y using `double Y=v[i]`. The whole code looks as follows:

```
double X = func();
dx=0.01;
int i = std::size_t(X/dx);
double Y = v[i];
print(Y)
```

This method correctly gives the expected value for the index i within the range [0, length(v)].

My main issue is not with finding the index, but using it: `X` is determined from an auxiliary function, and whenever I need to set `Y=v[i]` using the index determined above the code becomes extremely slow.
Without commenting or removing any of the lines, the code becomes much faster when setting X to some random value between 0 and 1 right after its definition or by setting i to some random value between 0 and length of v after the third line.

Could anyone be able to tell why this occurs? The speed changes of a factor 1000 if not more, and since there are only additional steps in the faster method and `func()` is called anyway I can't understand why it should become faster.

Comment: please read about [mcve] and try to provide one. Without the code it is impossible to tell why it is faster/slower

Comment: Measuring code speed in C++ is difficult and there's tons of pitfalls. Please show us how you measured.

Comment: With all the values known beforehand, it is possible to do division and converting to integer at compile time. `Y = v[42];` would be faster than also computing i.

Comment: Make sure you compile with optimizations enabled.

Comment: What is the size of bins (v) array?

Comment: As others have mentioned, we need to see the actual code. For example. When you say : "X to some random value between 0 and 1", you could be meaning that the value was obtained from a random number generator, or that you put in a constant. That changes things a lot, and we can't tell which it is from your description. And that's just one example amongst many.

Comment: So if you replace `func()` with something else the code becomes slow? Could it be that `func()` simply is slow or much more random than whatever you replace it with?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have put no code in the question, there has to be a wild-guess like this:

- You didn't sort all the X results before accessing lookup table. Processing a sorted array is faster.
- Some of X had denormalized values which took a toll on computation time for certain CPU types including yours.
- The dataset is too big for the L3 cache and it accessed RAM always, instead of quick cache hits that were seen in the other test.
- Compiler was optimizing all of the expensive function calls out, but in real-world test scenario, it is not.
- Time measurement has bugs
- Computer is not stable in performance (like being a shared server or an antivirus intervention feeding on RAM bandwidth)